# Prevent users from stopping a process

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, process

Long story short, I need to create an application that monitor the sound volume on a computer. The computer's user must not be able to stop the application no matter what.

I'll need to make my app start on computer start up, so the user can't just restart it to enter his session without the application running. As of now I don't know precisely how to do it but with some research this shouldn't be a problem.

My biggest concern is if he just stops the process in the task manager. I guess that I can't avoid that programmatically ? Is there a way to just modify the session's right so that it can't stop processes in the task manager? Or any other solution I didn't think about ?

Or there is no way I can do that and I'll just have to trust my user not to ever stop the program in the task manager ?

Thanks in advance for your help. :)

PS : This will run on a computer in a student club that runs the music for the club and that anyone can access. There are chambers where people sleep the floors above so we don't want people to put the volume too loud. That's it. No malware or anything.

Comment: This is not a programming question and thus doesn't belong on this site.  But no, there's no way to prevent someone from stopping a process.

Comment: Imagine someone made a program that you could never stop... and then they installed it on your PC... and you could never remove it. Do you like the sound of that? I bet malware authors do

Comment: Best thing you can do it create it as a service, that way it's harder to find and won't appear on the task manager process list. Either way, it's impossible to completely hide something.

Comment: "No malware or anything." the comments weren't to (necessarily) imply that you were looking to create malware, but if functionality like this existed, it would make malware creators jobs ***much*** simpler.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/volumelimiter/ and maybe lock the machine down so processes can't be ended w/o elevated privileges ?  This doesn't seem programming related.

Comment: We want to make something that slowly decrease the sound overtime so, basically what you linked with just a bit more functionalities, but thanks. What do you mean locking the machine down ?

Comment: Start the program as an administrator and don't let other users login as an administrator.  If you don't trust the people to have full access to the machine, don't given them an administrative account.  You can then give them access to do only what you want them to be able to do.

Comment: Run it as a service and configure permissions appropriately, so that regular user (I hope computers at student club are not running under admin) cannot stop it.

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne: By default, service processes are listed in Task Manager's Processes list (except the ones that deserve drivers). As strictly related to Task Manager there is a trick to hide a process from it (by sending [LVM_DELETEITEM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774895(v=vs.85).aspx) at a rate equal or more to its refresh period - I've did it a while ago from C), but that wouldn't cover you against other tools like _Process Explorer_ or _tasklist_ / _taskkill_. You could restrict other users to stop your app via privileges, or you could hide _Volume Control_

Answer (score 1):

In general, the only programs that act like that are malicious (e.g. [rootkits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rootkit)). If you think about it, you really wouldn't *want* programs to be able to act like that.

As others have indicated, the closest you'll get here is a Windows Service, which automatically starts with Windows. Average users won't know to stop it, but it's still possible to stop it manually for power users.

One work-around you could try is to periodically have it call a web service to verify that it's running. That way you could tell who might have uninstalled or stopped the service. (The problem, of course, is that they might just not have their computer on or something; you could have separate calls for "Start" and "Still On").

Alternatively, if this installed only on computers that are exclusively under your direct control, as others have indicated, you could configure things so that you need administrative access to stop the process. This option was addressed in the comments.

Comment: "you could configure things so that you need administrative access to stop the process" and how do I do that ?

Comment: @Kishlin That option is described in the comments

Answer (score 0):

I'm not accusing you of malware - just wanted to illustrate how bad it would be if you could easily make a program that the user can "never stop".

### So *no* you can't make a program that a computer-savvy person could never stop.

But from what I gathered....

Sounds like you want to make it a service. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(v=vs.110).aspx.

Another (easier I think) option is just to make a console app that starts up from the Task Scheduler http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/manas1/console-application-using-windows-scheduler/.